# Is it possible to do prioritization among 3 or more beans in a @Component class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Just for clarification, I have a `@Component` class with two wired beans. I want to prioritize each bean. Is that possible to do?

```
@Component
public class SecureMessages {

    @Autowired // load second
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired // load first
    private LocalCacheServiceImpl LocalCacheServiceImpl;
}
```

As per the above code I want to create a bean for local cache initially while calling this component class and then the rest of the beans can get created.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `@Order` annotation to your components. Lower order value has a higher priority. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html).

```
@Bean
@Order(2)
public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper(){
    return new ObjectMapper();
}

@Bean
@Order(1)
public LocalCacheServiceImpl getLocalCacheServiceImpl(){
    return new LocalCacheServiceImpl();
}
```

`@DependsOn` could *maybe* also be suitable for you. It depends why you want order your beans. You can read about it [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html)

Comment: The documentation you linked states the following: **While such order values may influence priorities at injection points, please be aware that they do not influence singleton startup order which is an orthogonal concern determined by dependency relationships and @DependsOn declarations (influencing a runtime-determined dependency graph)**. So in my understanding, the `@Order` annotation has no effect on *creation* of the beans, only on injecting them in the same component. I think that OP is looking for the `@DependsOn` annotation.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I did however understand that OP want to load the beans in a specific order - hence the code snipper `// load second` and `// load first`. This is why I said `@DependsOn` could *maybe* be used. I think it is hard to tell if OP refers to bean creation or bean injection.

Comment: I found this Jira issue about the confusion about the two annotations. https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16213

Comment: Yes, I agree that the question is not clear enough. My comment was addressing the fact that you used the `@Order` annotation on a `@Bean` annotated method, which (in 99% of the cases) creates a singleton. So I am not sure if the Order annotation has an effect in the example above.